# Environment texture shows up different in viewport / camera view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera

[image: left is viewport, right is camera view, bottom is the scene]

Hi! Im fairly new to blender and having some trouble here. Essentially I have my letters inside of a glass cylinder mesh, when im in the viewport it looks fine and the green glass distorts the environment texture like I want. For some reason when I select the camera view and or render it, the environment texture cuts through and does not get distorted through the glass.

Also, when I turn the camera about 90 degrees to the right I can actually see a seam where the camera view does show the proper distortion but there's a seam where that cuts off and is just the regular background? kind of confused and really would appreciate some help. Thanks!